# Use Python interpreter from another Docker container

Tags: python, r, docker, docker-compose, reticulate

I want to run several R packages that have Python dependencies and in some sort act as wrappers, but I can't use the Python interpreter that comes in the Python container with reticulate's `use_python()`.

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  python:
    image: 
      python:3.9.5-slim-buster
    command: 
      python3 -m http.server
    volumes:
      - .:/project
      - python:/usr/local/bin
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  r-studio:
    build: 
      image: rstudio:4.1.2
    volumes:
      - .:/home/rstudio
      - python:/usr/local/bin/python
    ports:
      - "8787:8787"

volumes:
  python:
```

Whenever a script is executed in the R container using either of these commands

```
use_python("/usr/local/bin/python/python")
use_python("/usr/local/bin/python/python3")
use_python("/usr/local/bin/python/python3.9")
```

I always get the following error

```
Error in system2(command = python, args = shQuote(script), stdout = TRUE,  : 
  error in running command
```

The same thing doesn't happen whenever I run r-studio's version of python using `Sys.which("python3")` as an argument (`/usr/bin/python3`). Nonetheless, I prefer to be using the python version of the other container.

Comment: That's true, you can't run binaries out of other containers; their filesystems are isolated from each other.  If you need multiple language runtimes for the same single program, you need to use a Dockerfile to install both into the same image.  The only thing your R container can do with the other container is make an HTTP call to it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Can you think of a solution that closely resembles my case, meaning that the installed packages are going to remain isolated in two different containers, one for R and one for Python?